# How to create queue of microsoft azure service bus using c#?

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

How can i create queue of microsoft azure service bus using c# code?

I have tried this , but it does not work:

```
string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists("testqueue")) {
   namespaceManager.CreateQueue("testqueue");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NamespaceManager` is coming from an old and deprecated Azure Service Bus .NET library [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus) that shouldn't be used for new development. Instead, the new .NET Standard client [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus) should be used. The new client provides similar functionality, but with slightly different constructs. The static `NamespaceManager` class is replaced with the `ManagementClient` class. The rest is logically identical with a minor difference that the IO-bound operations are asynchronous now.

```cs
var queueName = "testqueue";
var connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");

var client = new ManagementClient(connectionString);

if (!await client.QueueExistsAsync(queueName).ConfigureAwait(false))
{
  await client.CreateQueueAsync(new QueueDescription(queueName)
  {
    MaxDeliveryCount = int.MaxValue,
    LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    MaxSizeInMB = 5 * 1024,
    EnableBatchedOperations = true
  }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code,

```
public static void CreateQueue(NamespaceManager nameSpaceManager, string queueName)
        {
            if (!nameSpaceManager.QueueExists(queueName))
            {
                var qd = new QueueDescription(queueName)
                {
                    MaxSizeInMegabytes = 5120,
                    DefaultMessageTimeToLive = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)
                    //IsAnonymousAccessible = true
                };

                nameSpaceManager.CreateQueue(qd);
            }
        }
```

and call it

```
var nameSpaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(serviceBusConnectionString);
                CreateQueue(nameSpaceManager, queueName);
```